# JavaScript: Sort array of objects by computed property or by an existing property if equal

Tags: javascript

```
[
    { name: 'Joe', scores: [1, 2, 3] },
    { name: 'Jane', scores: [1, 2, 3] },
    { name: 'John', scores: [1, 2, 3] }
]
```

how do I make a function that sorts the elements first by the sum in scores and later by name?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: using the index of the list to get into the first aray and then tried to applya an index

Comment: and then i tried two for loops one to select the first aray and then get in the second

Comment: @nikstreat You will be able to get much better answers on here if you include the code that you tried to get working :)

Comment: when i googled i saw that this kind of stuff i tried is just not an option. Im looking for a way to be able ro reach scores so theat i can manipulate it but all i find is selekting an aray by thr value of the second item

Comment: @MajedBadawi what is the "...e" for?

Comment: It's called the spread operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), feel free to add questions to the answer below

Comment: @nikstreat I updated the answer with a simpler approach imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), sort the array by the sum of `scores`, or `name` as fallback (using [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare))

```js
const arr = [ { name: 'Joe', scores: [1] }, { name: 'Jane', scores: [1, 2] }, { name: 'John', scores: [1, 2] } ];

const sum = (arr = []) => arr.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0);

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => 
  sum(b.scores) - sum(a.scores) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for all sums and the object as key without mutating data.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'Joe', scores: [1, 2, 3] }, { name: 'Jane', scores: [1, 4, 3] }, { name: 'John', scores: [1, 2, 1] }],
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    sums = new Map(data.map(o => [o, o.scores.reduce(add, 0)]));

data.sort((a, b) => sums.get(b) - sums.get(a) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lodash` package could be handy

```
const lodash = require('lodash')

const list = [
  { name: 'Joe', scores: [1, 2, 4] },
  { name: 'Jane', scores: [1, 2, 3] },
  { name: 'John', scores: [1, 2, 4] }
]

const listWithSum = list.map(item => {
  return {
    ...item,
    sum: lodash.sum(item.scores)
  }
})

const sortedList = lodash.orderBy(listWithSum, ['score', 'name'], ['desc', 'desc'])

console.log(sortedList)
```